# How do you find images with a name similar to a variable?

Tags: php, image, search

So far, I wrote a script which finds if a certain file exists in an external website.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['user'])){
    if ($_GET['user'] != ""){
        $userloc = "http://somesite.com/images/" . htmlspecialchars($_GET["user"]) . ".png";
        $user = htmlspecialchars($_GET['user']);
        if (getimagesize($userloc) !== false) {
            echo $user . "exists!" ;
            echo "<img src=\"" . $userloc . "\" height=\"100px\" />";
        } else {
            echo $username . "\" does not exist.";
            $suggest = /* Code to find an image with a similar name */
            echo "Did you mean: <a href=\"index.php?user=" . $suggest . "\"></a>"; 
    }
}
?>
```

Basically, I would like to expand the code so it will display image suggestions.
I am a complete newbie when it comes to PHP code. Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: You would need to be able to obtain a list of images from the external site or else you have infinite possibilities.

Comment: How can you suggest something when you don't know what is available? If `somesite.com` is your site, you could generate an array containing all images,..

Comment: Also, your code does not check if the image exists.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is for escaping text going into an html context. it is UTTERLY useless for generating URLs.

Comment: The site "somesite.com" is not mine. An idea might be to generate maybe 10-30 respellings of "$user", then to see if any of those respellings exist. (May seem barbaric, but may also be the only option)

Comment: In that case, how would a PHP function generate 30 respellings of a word? (but not case-sensitive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [levenshtein](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) function is useful for finding similarities in strings.

Assuming that you have correctly checked to see that a file exists or not, then you can use this function to make suggestions.

```
/**
 * @param string   $inputName
 * @param string[] $knownNames
 *
 * @return string[]
 */
function getNameSuggestions($inputName, array $knownNames = array())
{
    $candidates = array();
    foreach ($knownNames as $candidate) {
        $lev = levenshtein($inputName, $candidate);
        if ($lev <= strlen($inputName) / 3 || false !== strpos($candidate, $inputName)) {
            $candidates[] = $candidate;
        }
    }

    return $candidates;
}
```

Then call the function

```
$suggestions = getNameSuggestions((string) $_GET['user'], array(
    // a list of known users
));
```

Comment: +1'd because didn't even know that this function existed in php

Comment: I will look into that. The only problem is that there are about 14,530,014 images in this folder, and I have no clue what those images are called. It may help if I state that the folder is the skin library for Minecraft. :)

Comment: I do not know how long it would take to create an array with every image's name in it. It might shorten the time if the script finds every image starting with the same letter as "$user", then to create an array out of that. —I also do not know how to create an array from an external website. :)

Comment: The [Symfony Finder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html) could help you scan for all files in given directories without having to hardcode them in.

Comment: Would it return a single array?

Comment: @user2977210 Unfortunately not. You'd have to do a foreach and populate an array with `$file->getFilename()` or `$file->getRealpath()`, whichever is more suitable for you.

Comment: ok, I just tried using the levenshtein function above, and all it printed was `"Array"`. I'm not sure what went wrong.

Comment: It's supposed to return an array of suggestions. I figured you might want to do something with that array. Otherwise just grab the first one `$suggestions[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not test if a file exist on a remote website. What it does it assumes that the filename `$_GET['user'] . 'png';` exists at `http://somesite.com/images/` if it's not `""`

What you should do is something like this:

```
$remote = 'http://somesite.com/images/' . urlencode($_GET["user"]) . '.png';

if (file_get_contents($remote) !== false) {
    echo 'Exists!';
} else {
    echo 'Does not exist!';

    // try something else or start bruteforce :P
}
```

Comment: Don't `urlencode()` the entire URL or it won't work.

Comment: Hmmm… you are right. The code that I pasted does not seem to be checking if the file exists (I had a larger amount of code and it seems I left out a part). I will append that now.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I didn't know that are you sure?

Comment: When I did `echo file_get_contents(urlencode('http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/'));`, I got "AccessDeniedAccess Denied3B49F24A89FDF4760vlwyUdSa1ImBA1n+x1v4fNjbSi51cgNuHCgSXow+VjO+P/ee1Ij4rtiJGYX0MeQ"